How to run pipewire before kwin_wayland or link pipewire with existing kwin?
At first I could not record my desktop, using OBS or Spectacle. The problem was "Failed to get Pipewire context". In OBS it said, warning: [pipewire] Failed to start screencast, denied or cancelled by user. Searching the internet didn't help much. Like I have all the box ticked for recodring the screen (have xdg-desktop-portal-kde installed and all). Finally, I found if I kill kwin_wayland, a new kwin_wayland process spawn and in this one I can screen-capture and everything. So, basically I have to run pipewire,pipewire-pulse and wireplumber before kwin_wayland to capture screen from kwin. How do I run them before kwin fires up?
For context, I do not use systemd, so I have to run a startup script in KDE to start pipewire. Now, the workaround is to kill the kwin in that script after I start the pipewire and related processes. It seems bit messy. Is there a proper way to do it? That is to link the pipewire with existing kwin instance or run it before kwin ?
